# For loop in the backEnd class not working?

Tags: java, for-loop

The for loop in the backEnd class - CompareGuess method is not working.
....................................................................................................................................................

```
public class frontEnd
{  
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    int GetGuess = 0;
    backEnd e1 = new backEnd();  
    e1.InitializeArray(); 
    while(e1.chanceCounter<3)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a number");
      GetGuess = (int)(Math.random()*6);
      System.out.println(GetGuess);
      e1.UserGuess(GetGuess);
      e1.CompareGuess();
      if(e1.suc!=1)
      {
        System.out.println("It is a miss");      
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorry, no chances left");           

  }  
}    


class backEnd
{
  int Guess;
  int HitCounter=0;
  int[] abc = new int[7] ; 
  int chanceCounter=0;
  int suc = 0;
  int x =0;
  public void InitializeArray()
  {
    abc[1]= 3;
    abc[2] = 5;
    abc[4] = 1;
  } 

  public void UserGuess(int guess) 
  {
    Guess = guess;
  }

  public void CompareGuess() 
  {
    for(x=0; x<=6; x++ )
    {
      if (abc[x] == Guess) 
      {
        System.out.println("It is a hit");
        chanceCounter = chanceCounter + 1;
        suc = 1;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What's it supposed to do and what is it doing?

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide *nearly* enough information. What happens, and what did you expect to happen? What diagnostic steps have you performed so far? (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you take the time to follow normal Java naming conventions and also format your sample code...)

Comment: I see a `break` outside the `if` statement. Move it inside the `}` otherwise your `for` loop only executes once.

Comment: @JonSkeet new to Java, will keep in mind all the points raised by you...  Johnny Mopp.. thanks ,...

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be here:

```
for(x=0; x<=6; x++ )
{
  if (abc[x] == Guess) 
  {
     System.out.println("It is a hit");
     chanceCounter = chanceCounter + 1;
     suc = 1;
  }

  break; //Here
 }
```

Look what your code does:

- Your `for` loop makes the first iteration, taking `x = 0`
- If `abc[x]` it's equals to `Guess` then your program executes the code inside the if statement. After, the break statement will be executed.
- If not, it just execute the `break` statement

So, in both cases, the `break` statement it's going to be executed in the first iteration (therefore, your program will go out of the `for` loop).

Look that your program only will execute your first iteration but not the rest `(x = 1, x = 2 [....] x =6)`.

If you want that your `for` loop go through all the iterations you have to remove your `break` statement from your code.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: You are welcome ;) And please consider to mark it as accepted answer if it helped to solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your game is all about guessing. I took a guess at what it's supposed to do then I rewrote your code, because I couldn't bear to leave it as it was. I left it as similar to your as I can cope with:

```
public class FrontEnd
{  
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    int getGuess = 0;
    BackEnd e1 = new BackEnd();  
    e1.initializeArray(); 
    int totalChances = 3;

    while(e1.chanceCounter < totalChances)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a number");
      getGuess = (int)(Math.random()*6);
      System.out.println(getGuess);
      e1.userGuess(getGuess);
      e1.compareGuess();
      if(!e1.suc)
      {
        System.out.println("It is a miss");      
      }
      e1.suc = false;
      e1.chanceCounter++;
    }

    System.out.println("Sorry, no chances left");
    System.out.println("you scored " + e1.hitCounter + " out of " + totalChances);          

  }  
}    


class BackEnd
{
  int guess;
  int hitCounter = 0;
  int[] abc = new int[7] ; 
  int chanceCounter = 0;
  boolean suc = false;

  public void initializeArray()
  {
    abc[1] = 3;
    abc[2] = 5;
    abc[4] = 1;
  } 

  public void userGuess(int guess) 
  {
    this.guess = guess;
  }

  public void compareGuess() 
  {
    for( int x = 0; x <= 6; x++ )
    {
      if (abc[x] == guess) 
      {
        System.out.println("It is a hit");
        hitCounter++;
        suc = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As others have said the `break` statement is supposed to be inside the conditional block. Also it looks like you were forgetting to reset the `suc` variable after each guess. Also you weren't using `hitCounter` at all. I assumed it's for counting correct guesses, which left me wondering when to update `chanceCounter`: either after each guess or after each wrong guess. I didn't know if the guesser was supposed to run out of chances after 3 guesses, or after 3 wrong guesses. I went with the former and update the `chanceCounter` after every guess.

guesses of 0 are considered correct because they match with all the entries in the `abc` array that are not initialised.

Comment: Thanks a ton, will do the necessary changes.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works the way you want please mark my answer as accepted. That's the best way to thank me.